# Angular2/Nativescript: when building my app Nativescript looks for a file in the wrong place

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to build a small nativescript app and as soon as it gets deployed on my genymotion device I get the following error:.  So it seems like it can't find my product model?  I checked and as far as I can see I import the product model correctly everywhere.  Am I missing something?  Any idea what else I can look at?

The imports of the two controllers that use the product model:

```
/*from "/app/app.component.ts:*/ import { ProductModel } from './models/product.model';

/*from /app/pages/product/product.component.ts:*/ import { ProductModel } from '../../models/product.model';
```

my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./models/product.model", relative to: /app/models/
    com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:244)
    com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:238)
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Lo
```

Comment: Based on the error log you are calling './models/product.model' from a file already located in /app/models/ and as far as I understood the models folder is at your root level (like app/models) . Perhaps you should find that call and change it to "./product.model"

Comment: @Nick Iliev that's the strange thing...  The only file in app/models is product.model which only has a constructor...

Comment: rm -rf platforms .. then uninstall the app in Geny and then try to rebuild.. sometimes Geny is not so reliable